# PHP Count rows then subtract from static number

Tags: php, count, subtraction

I am trying to count the number of rows in a table with a where clause. I then want to subtract from a static number (the # of stalls owned - how many stalls are used by boarders).

I ran this through a PHP validator, looked through stackoverflow for anything similar, and while there are no errors all it does is show the number 16. It does not subtract the row count from 16. Obviously I'm doing it wrong!

```
<?php
$result = mysqli_query("SELECT count(*) FROM boarders WHERE boardtype LIKE 'Stall%'");
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
$num = $row[0];
echo (16 - $num);
?>
```

I got what I wanted to work. No, it isn't mysqli and needs updated to that but I haven't learned it yet and will (hopefully) at some point. I just muck about with code for myself, not anything important. The below functions exactly how I want though so fine for right now.

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS stallboarders FROM boarders WHERE boardtype LIKE 'Stall%'"; 
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

echo (16-$row['stallboarders']);
}
?>
```

Comment: @JayBlanchard `$num = $row[0];` - I guess *Sam*, in a way.

Comment: Ah - yes, I see that now. *Ralph* @Fred-ii-

Comment: @OP: Make sure that row is an `int` and not VARCHAR. Also use `SELECT *` instead of `SELECT count(*)`

Comment: @Fred-ii- `COUNT(*)` is always an INT.

Comment: @OP You're not connecting to your DB. `$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT...` `or die(mysqli_error($con)` and error reporting http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: Wondering if this question should just be closed based on ^^^

Comment: Along with what @Fred-ii- said, if you had any error checking at all you would know why there was no return from your query.

Comment: You should be getting an error from that code, it should complain that the first argument to `mysqli_query` is the wrong type. Make sure you have error reporting enabled (isn't that usually your line @Fred-ii- ?)

Comment: @Barmar LOL, usually. I'll just add that.

Comment: It is connected to my database through an include with all my connection information.  I put that together wrong so will go fix it. I'm trying to count how many rows there are... not a value per each row. Isn't count(*) to count all the rows?

Comment: @user3064125 Your code shows `mysqli_query("SELECT` instead of `$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT`. Tell me how that will connect to your db? We don't know which variable you're using to connect with, yet alone the API. `mysqli_` - `mysql_` - PDO? Your posted code clearly shows you're not connecting to DB.

Comment: Sorry, yes, I'm fixing that. However, will the code I have (once connected) count up how many rows there are and then subtract from 16? That is something I've never done before so not sure if that code even makes any sense.

Comment: Then update your question/code with what you're really using. This is guesswork, *at best*.

Comment: @JayBlanchard with `mysqli_`? plus that doesn't work with select ;-)

Comment: @JayBlanchard http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php *PDOStatement::rowCount() returns the number of rows affected by a DELETE, INSERT, or UPDATE statement.* - doesn't work with `SELECT`. Therefore, if OP's using PDO, would need to use `count()`. ;-) *How 'bout that drink now Sam?*

Comment: @Fred-ii- OR [`columnCount`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.columncount.php)

Comment: Have a look @Fred-ii- I had just finished the re-edit ;-) *I'm ready to toast Mr. Nimoy now.*

Comment: @JayBlanchard Toast and Scotch; *lethal combo Sam!* - Mr. Nimoy's spaced out by now.

Comment: Yes, just close this.... I'm messing about with this and scrapped it all.

Comment: Well @user3064125 if I find a solution, and the question's still open, I'll post an answer. Just make sure you've passed DB connection to your query if you haven't already done so. It's hard to know what you're using to connect with; `mysqli_` or `mysql_` or PDO. If I knew, I'd be able to help you more, and/or others. I know you have `mysqli_query()`, but many do mix APIs which don't intermix with each other, that's why I asked.

Comment: @user3064125 I tested your code now, having 2 rows. One being "id" as an `int` and "boardtype" as VARCHAR, with 2 entries Stall 1 and Stall 2. Echo'd result was 14. `$row[0]` is related to `int` column. If I use `$num = $row[1];` then I get 16, which that is the "boardtype" column. Which could explain a few things. MySQL needs an integer to count with, and not a string/varchar.

Comment: I figured it out. Still need to learn all the new stuff with PDO/mysqli etc but for now it works. Thanks everyone.

Comment: @user3064125 Great and you're welcome, you can post your answer if you like. I for one would surely like to know what you did as a solution. Now, would it have anything to do with [the comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28771422/php-count-rows-then-subtract-from-static-number#comment45822385_28771422) I left just above or about the DB connection?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS stallboarders FROM boarders WHERE boardtype LIKE 'Stall%'"; 
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

echo (16-$row['stallboarders']);
}
?>
```

Comment: Ah, so you were probably mixing `mysql_` and `mysqli_` APIs which don't intermix together. My `mysqli_` method worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you did enter your own answer as I mentioned in comments that you could, am submitting the following in order to show where the mistake was made from your posted code.

```
$result = mysqli_query("SELECT
                       ^ missing connection to DB
```

is missing the DB connection parameter `$result = mysqli_query($db_connection,"SELECT`

and is required with `mysqli_query()` http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php
(`mysqli_` functions).

***Sidenote:*** Testing your answer with my own, produced the same results.

It's obvious that you were mixing MySQL APIs in not passing DB connection to your query.

- Those different APIs do not intermix with each other.

Here is a mysqli method which you should have used, and passing DB connection to your query.

```
<?php 

$DB_HOST = 'xxx';
$DB_USER = 'xxx';
$DB_PASS = 'xxx';
$DB_NAME = 'xxx';

$Link = new mysqli($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME);
if($Link->connect_errno > 0) {
  die('Connection failed [' . $Link->connect_error . ']');
}

$result = mysqli_query($Link,"SELECT count(*) 
          FROM boarders WHERE boardtype LIKE 'Stall%'");
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);

// will return 14 with 2 rows in table
$num = $row[0]; // id is int

// debug test
// will return 16
// $num = $row[1]; // boardtype is varchar

// will echo 14 with 2 rows in table
echo (16 - $num);
```

---

`$row[0]` should be an `int` type in order to get proper results.